# Velocity derivatives using Quaternions

Tags: kinematics

How to compute the angular and linear velocities Quaternions? I am new to this area and although I have studied the algebra I am unable to understand how to compute the velocities.

Comment: Could you be more precise here, what exactly you want? E.g. you have two quaternions, and you want to get the rotation between them?

Comment: If they open again, I will try to answer your queston.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is of course to get yourself familiar with geometric algebra first.

```
Lounesto, Pertti. Clifford algebras and spinors. Vol. 286. Cambridge university press, 2001.
```

After that, everything can be derived by yourself. But I guess most people here only like quick and dirty approaches. Use this book instead:

```
Kuipers, Jack B. Quaternions and rotation sequences. Vol. 66. Princeton: Princeton university press, 1999.
```

straightly answers your question.

If you want to have more geometric sense of the algebra manipulations, John McCarthy's couldn't have done it better.

```
McCarthy, J. Michael. Introduction to theoretical kinematics. MIT press, 1990.
McCarthy, J. Michael, and Gim Song Soh. Geometric design of linkages. Vol. 11. Springer, 2010.
```

Answer (score 1):

When I studied the relationship between the rotation matrix and quaternion, I have found a literature, here is [the link](http://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/kinematics/angularvelocity/QuaternionDifferentiation2.pdf). I think it will instruct you how to compute the velocity derivatives using quaternions.

Comment: +1 for http://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/kinematics/angularvelocity/.  That site is huge and great for all kinds of math stuff.